# elasticbeanstalk supervisord can't get env

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

I need to use supervisord to spin up a daphne server which needs to connect to DB. However the credentials are in `/opt/python/current/env`. I tried to do `source /opt/python/current/env` and `reload/restart` supervisord. It's still not picking up the env, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of directly use 'source' in the supervisord command, I put it into bash file along with activate the virtual env, and it works fine now